# Eclipse Scout set text position in fields

Tags: text, position, field, eclipse-scout

I have a "grid" of different fields in Scout Neon (M5) application.
My problem is that `String` and number (`BigDecimal` for example) fields has different text position in field.

In `String` field, text is positioned on left side, and in `BigDecimal` (and other number fields) text is positioned on right side. 
I understand why by default this is a case, but in grid layout it really doesn't look good.

[image]

How to change text position in fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the property `horizontalAlignment` to `-1`.

```
public class IntegerField extends AbstractIntegerField {

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredHorizontalAlignment() {
    return -1;
  }

}
```

It is not obvious though because the javadoc says that this property configures the horizontal alignment of the field inside a group box. This is is true as well, but only if `fillHorizontal` is set to `false`.

So currently the property is used for 2 purposes:

- Controlling the alignment of the field in a grid cell, if `fillHorizontal` is `false`
- Controlling the alignment of the content of the field, which is what you need